# How to solve com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter: -1

Tags: java, itext

I use itext5 to generate a pdf file,there is an exception when I called `pdfStamper.close()`:

```
com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter: -1
Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter: -1
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.ArrayRandomAccessSource.get(ArrayRandomAccessSource.java:60) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:211) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readChar(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:412) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CFFFont.getCard16(CFFFont.java:206) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CFFFont.getIndex(CFFFont.java:266) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CFFFont.<init>(CFFFont.java:1074) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CFFFontSubset.<init>(CFFFontSubset.java:169) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TtfUnicodeWriter.writeFont(TtfUnicodeWriter.java:74) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.writeFont(TrueTypeFontUnicode.java:368) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FontDetails.writeFont(FontDetails.java:400) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1361) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:280) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:230) ~[itextpdf-5.5.13.jar!/:5.5.13]
    at com.jingli.creditchain.service.seal.Paperless.getPDF(Paperless.java:89) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.jingli.creditchain.service.seal.SealService.lambda$preview$1(SealService.java:179) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.jingli.creditchain.utils.JingliAsyncFuture.lambda$run$0(JingliAsyncFuture.java:21) ~[classes!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

My main code is like this, they can add words and table to the field of PDF template:

```java
byte[] getPDF(Map<String, String> fieldMap, Map<String, List<List<String>>> tableMap, Template template) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); InputStream is = getFileFromTemplate(template.fileName())) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("AdobeFangsongStd-Regular.otf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            ArrayList<BaseFont> fontList = new ArrayList<>();
            fontList.add(bf);
            form.setSubstitutionFonts(fontList);

            if (fieldMap != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> field : fieldMap.entrySet()) {
                    addValueToField(field.getKey(), field.getValue(), form, stamper, bf);
                }
            }

            if (tableMap != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<String>>> entry : tableMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    List<List<String>> tableData = entry.getValue();
                    addTableToField(key, tableData, form, stamper, bf);
                }
            }

            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamper.close();//exception was throwed from here
            return os.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.warn("get pdf", ex);

        }
    }
```

Function *addValueToField*, it can add words to field.I didn't use `form.setField(key,value)`because it resulted in the embedding of font file,pdf file would be too large(over 20M) at last,which is unacceptable.

```
    private void addValueToField(String key, String value, AcroFields form, PdfStamper stamper, BaseFont bf) {
        Font font = new Font(bf, 14.04f);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(value, font);
        List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldPositions = form.getFieldPositions(key);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fieldPositions)) {
            for (AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition : fieldPositions) {
                PdfContentByte pcb = stamper.getOverContent(fieldPosition.page);
                Rectangle signRect = fieldPosition.position;

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                float totalWidth = signRect.getRight() - signRect.getLeft() - 1;
                table.setTotalWidth(totalWidth);


                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chunk));
                cell.setFixedHeight(signRect.getTop() - signRect.getBottom() - 1);
                cell.setBorderWidth(0);
                cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                cell.setLeading(0, (float) 1.1);


                table.addCell(cell);
                table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, signRect.getLeft(), signRect.getTop(), pcb);
            }
        }
    }
```

Function *addTableToField*

```
    private void addTableToField(String key, List<List<String>> tableData, AcroFields form, PdfStamper stamper, BaseFont bf) throws DocumentException {
        List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldPositions = form.getFieldPositions(key);
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fieldPositions)) {
            for (AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition : fieldPositions) {
                PdfContentByte pcb = stamper.getOverContent(fieldPosition.page);
                Rectangle signRect = fieldPosition.position;

                int column = tableData.get(0).size();
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(column);
                float totalWidth = signRect.getRight() - signRect.getLeft() - 1;
                int size = tableData.get(0).size();
                float[] width = new float[size];
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        width[i] = 60f;
                    } else {
                        width[i] = (totalWidth - 60) / (size - 1);
                    }
                }
                table.setTotalWidth(width);
                table.setLockedWidth(true);
                table.setKeepTogether(true);
                table.setSplitLate(false);
                table.setSplitRows(true);
                Font FontProve = new Font(bf, 10, 0);

                for (List<String> list : tableData) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(String.valueOf(list.get(j)), FontProve);
                        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);

                        cell.setBorderWidth(1);
                        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        cell.setLeading(0, (float) 1.4);
                        table.addCell(cell);
                    }
                }
                table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, signRect.getLeft(), signRect.getTop(), pcb);
            }
        }
    }
```

I read the 
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5tys.png)
I can't believe this code can throw the exception,is this a bug in itext?

Comment: your offset shouldnt be negative ->   array[number here should >=0]

Comment: I know that,but I have no way to control the offset,it's in the source code of itext

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote which caused the exception?

Comment: I have added the code, it's so long.

Answer (score 0):

I tried anything I could do util I added `stamper.flush()` before `stamper.close()`,but I don't understand the reason.